# Get Ip From Client Apache and Php

Tags: php, apache, ip

Want to ask, but maybe this question is a duplicate. I'm sorry that all the answers to the other questions didn't work in my case.

## Question

I have a server with apache as webserver running php+7.4 with default settings and certbot as SSL with public IP 192.168.1.11, I want to retrieve the IP of the client that opens my website, for example the domain news.test.com. test.com domain itself has a public ip address example 123.100.1.10. **how do i get the client ip that opens the news.test.com domain?**

## Already do

I already do this to get IP

```
public static function get_ip() {
    $mainIp = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $mainIp = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $mainIp = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $mainIp;
}
```

## Problem

Problem I got was not the IP client I got but instead got the IP from the test.com domain. I have tried another internet connection and did a public IP test, but I still get the IP from test.com not the client IP, Is it because the settings from my parent domain or from my apache are in the wrong settings? or there is an error or other way to get the client IP.?

Comment: `getenv()` is wrong in this case. Try it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64174081/2412335 -

Comment: Retrieving the IP address of a client is notoriously unreliable. In your case I'd guess there's a reverse proxy handling inbound requests, and it's not setting all the headers, so you'll only ever see the IP address of that server. Note also that 192.168.1.11 is not a public address. It might be the address of your server, but the 192.168.x.x block is specifically reserved for private addresses.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular yap i know is not public ip, its just my example. I tried with the same application that I made with a different server, the server can display the same ip as in https://ipinfo.io/

Comment: @digijay still getting ip from server https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/12129316?key=f63b9c1d1e3b2d0046b644c41759fd25, 
I think, the error is not in my php script, but the settings on my apache webserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a try with HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP

```
    public static function get_ip() {
    $mainIp = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $mainIp = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $mainIp = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $mainIp = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $mainIp;
}
```

Comment: still getting ip from server https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/12129316?key=f63b9c1d1e3b2d0046b644c41759fd25, 
I think, the error is not in my php script, but the settings on my apache webserver